# Regex select hostname only

Tags: regex

How to adjust the regex below to ignore network address and comments with `#` and just match hostname?

**regex:**

```
^((?!\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b).)*$
```

**string:**

```
localhost,127.0.0.1
8.8.8.8;web
web2 # Comments
192.168.0.1,fw
```

**output:**

[image]

**desired output:**

- localhost
- web
- web2
- fw

Comment: Try `#.*(*SKIP)(*F)|[\d_]*[A-Za-z]\w*`, see https://regex101.com/r/j8hohV/1

Comment: It worked perfectly, does this regex work in python?

Comment: With PyPi regex module. What do you need, just extract as a list of strings?

Comment: Exact, just a string list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
#.*|([\d_]*[A-Za-z]\w*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8hohV/3).

Only keep Group 2 matches, the rest can be dropped. If you use `re.findall`, it will fetch empty items where `#.*` matched, so you may simply remove all empty matches upon `re.findall` call.

**Details**:

- `#.*` - `#` and the rest of the line
- `|` - or
- `([\d_]*[A-Za-z]\w*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[\d_]*` - zero or more digits or underscores
  - `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `\w*` - zero or more word chars (any letters, digits, underscores)

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/m7Jn5L):

```
import re
text = '''localhost,127.0.0.1
8.8.8.8;web
web2 # Comments
192.168.0.1,fw''' 
print ([x for x in re.findall(r'#.*|([\d_]*[A-Za-z]\w*)', text) if x])
# => ['localhost', 'web', 'web2', 'fw']
```

Comment: Perfect, this regex combined your last answer helped me to leave the performatic algorithm !!!